# Whatsapp like CAB launch and onClick handling

Tags: android, onitemlongclicklistener

**WhatsApp behavior:**
 Inside the individual chat when we long click a image it launches the CAB, independent of where I long click horizontally. Now same behavior happens even if I long click to the left empty space beside an thumbnail(refer below image for refrence).

**My Issue:**
I know this is easily achievable through MultiChoiceModeListener, but issue here is when I apply individual onClick for the image(so that image opens in a separate full screen controller) at this point the onClick of individual thumbnail takes over the long click and CAB won't launch even if I keep longclicking on the thumbnail. CAB only launches when I longclick at the empty space beside the thumbnail[image]

**Question:**
How to do this behavior.

*Taking about the right side image and the empty area beside the thumbnail*

Code: 
ListItem xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_id"
    style="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                long viewId = view.getId();
                if (viewId == R.id.custom_tv) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only text item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ListView remaining area clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
//code to operate on selected views
});
```

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview, null);
            holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tv);
            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });
```

The above code in adapter class gives same behavior even if I just put a direct onClick on the image inside getView()

Comment: Can you post your layout and java code...?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your imageview xml

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

If your need it done programmatically then add this in your java code :

```
your_image_view.setLongClickable(true);
```

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. In your case can't you give a ItemLongClick event for your ListView....? And  do the CAB stuff in there.

Comment: I was hoping that to find a solution using setMultiChoiceModeListener(), but haven't found one till now. So is there a way(link/refrence) to launch multi mode of CAB from inside long click listener of whole listItem ?